# How to add new module to running ejabberd node?

Tags: ejabberd

I followed up this tutorial https://blog.process-one.net/elixir-sips-ejabberd-with-elixir-part-1/ how to write ejabberd module. And that works great, I put module to ejabberd/src and then compile everything.

But that seams as lot of work for me. Every time when I change one line of code during development I have to compile ejabberd again from scratch with new changed module. Is there any way that I can compile module and then just copy it to ejabberd modules path?

If yes, where is ejabberd modules path? And if yes what tutorial should I read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example usage: edit src/mod_echo.erl to add some relevant change. And now:

```
$ make
Compiled src/mod_echo.erl
$ sudo make install
...
$ ejabberdctl update_list
mod_echo
$ ejabberdctl update mod_echo
```

Since now, the new code is running in ejabberd.

In your case, you copy your module source files into ejabberd source path, and compile them as if they were another ejabberd modules. Or you can compile them separately, and install the *.beam files toghether with all the other ejabberd beam files (the location depends on your system).